# Unable to install Django Version 1.11.22 with python 2.7 installed on windows 10

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, pip, django-1.11

I have **python 2.7** installed on my machine globally and the pip version is **pip 20.3.4**. I want to install **Django version 1.11.22**. When I am trying to do so with `pip install Django==1.11.22`, I am getting the error as mentioned in the picture. This is not just while installing Django, I am getting the same error while installing anything like `pip install openpyxl`.

[image]

Comment: As the error says, since January 1st 2020, Python-2.x is no longer supported, and pip dropped support one year later.

Comment: So does that mean that there is no way of installing anything with python 2.7 as my interpreter because I am working on a web app that is dependent on this particular python version and it is not possible to migrate the app to python 3. Is there any way I can work with python 2.7 and install anything??

Comment: Python 2.7 is no longer supported or secure. I’m sorry, but don’t run it. NOTHING should be dependent on Python 2.7, especially anything web facing!

Comment: @Adii_Mathur Where from have you installed Python 2.7? Some Windows shop? chocolatey? or from python.org? PS. I'm sure it's still possible to install Python 2.7, pip and Django. There is nothing wrong in installing and using "not supported" Python.

Comment: @phd could you please tell me how that can be done with getting any error because I have tried everything but nothing seems to work

Comment: i got the python installation file from python.org and the exact version of python is 2.7.

Comment: @phd thank you so much, I was able to make it work without creating a virtual environment as well with python 2.7.5. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Adii_Mathur I made it an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version [Python 2.7.18](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/) should work fine. Install it with pip enabled or install pip after using `python -m ensurepip`. Upgrade pip:

```
pip install --upgrade "pip<21.0" "setuptools<45"
```

Install virtualenv:

```
pip install --upgrade "virtualenv<20"
```

Create a virtual environment  (very much recommended) somewhere and activate it:

```
virtualenv django-venv
django-venv\Scripts\activate.
```

Install Django (can be done without a virtual environment):

```
pip install --upgrade "Django==1.11.22".
```

Remember to activate the virtual environment (if you use it) every time you open a new terminal.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
As the error says and @Willem Van Onsem said, python 2.7 is no longer support, you can't install it nowadays